# How to modify a binary tree?

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, binary-tree

So basically I was presented with this question: https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-leaves-with-a-given-value/

> Given a binary tree root and an integer target, delete all the leaf nodes with value target.
>
> Note that once you delete a leaf node with value target, if it's parent node becomes a leaf node and has the value target, it should also be deleted (you need to continue doing that until you can't).

My solution was:

```
TreeNode* removeLeafNodes(TreeNode* root, int target) {
        if (!root)
            return nullptr;
        TreeNode* checkLeft = removeLeafNodes(root->left, target);
        TreeNode* checkRight = removeLeafNodes(root->right, target);
        if (!checkLeft and !checkLeft and root->val == target){
            root = nullptr;
        }
       return root;    
    }
```

However, this did not modify the original tree.

The correct code was:

```
TreeNode* removeLeafNodes(TreeNode* root, int target) {
        if (!root)
            return nullptr;
        root->left = removeLeafNodes(root->left, target);
        root->right = removeLeafNodes(root->right, target);
        if (!root->left and !root->right and root->val == target){
            root = nullptr;
        }
       return root;    
    }
```

How does mine not change the original tree?

Comment: This doesn't look like it compiles. Where are the declarations of `checkLeft`, and `checkRight`?

Comment: It sounds like you are operating on a copy of the tree or a copy of part of it. You might want to add some debugs into the copy constructor for TreeNode to see if this is the case. hth

Comment: Show us your full solution `checkRight` and `checkLeft` do not exist in your sample.

Comment: Oops! Forgot to add the declarations, but just added them in. @cigien

Comment: Just added the declarations in. @0x499602D2

Answer (score 0):

To modify the input true, you need to modify the `left`, and `right` nodes of the passed in pointer. Since you don't do that, the only time your code works is when the passed in tree has a single node.

To modify `root->left`, and `root->right`, you need to update them with the return values of the recursive calls, as written in the correct version.

Comment: So i typed my solution in and the same input tree was outputted. So i guess it is not deleting the leaf-nodes?